# Ubuntu keeps installing old kernels even though I don't need them

Tags: apt, kernel

I have the `/dev/sda1 /boot` full, so I looked for the heaviest folders and these happen to be two older linux kernels, e.g. the 4.4.0-22-generic and 4.4.0-21-generic. I am running on 4.4.0.36-generic.

I delete these kernels.

But then when I do

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

in order to solve unmet dependencies, they come back!

How do I get rid of them permanently?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo apt autoremove` instead of deleting the kernels manually?

Comment: I did, it still does not solve it.

Comment: I tried it a few times and it removed almost all of them now...

Comment: Can you update your question with the results of `ll /boot/vm*`?

Comment: I solved this by manually purging a bunch of files.. not ideal but now it works... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

causes update-initramfs to be run, which generates the initrd for the old kernels, which causes `/boot` to fill up again, even if you have cleared up space.

This is a long-standing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to uninstall old usued kernels:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Comment: this removes all sorts of different packages